# Unity 3D Load and Add Clip from folder C# script

Tags: c#, animation, load, unity-game-engine, clip

I need to load one specific animation clip from .fbx file and play it in loop.

I tried this:

```
GameObject go = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Animations/ubohost")) as GameObject;
```

ubohost.fbx is file with model and animation clip called mixiamo.com.

Then I am sure that I should add the animation to the gameobject:

```
Animation anim = go.AddComponent<Animation>();
```

And after that somehow add a clip, I tried many ways, but none works.

I know that it should be really easy, but I am not getting anywhere.

Basically I need just to load and play one animation with script.

Comment: I am not sure if this works with an FBX file directly. But a prefab can be loaded and intantiated successfully from Resources, so you might try this instead.

Comment: Ok, when I do this with .fbx file, the object appears on scene, even animation component is added. But I do not know, how to add the clip there. How to choose the clip from the loaded gameobject which contains animation for sure.

Comment: The `Animation` component should be already instantiated and must not be added. All clips should be visible in the animations array of Animation. Their state can be accessed via ["myAnimation"] and they are played with `Play`

Comment: Yes, it should.. but it is not. And I have no idea why.